# Sending a mail using PHP to my email account

Tags: php, sendmail

I tried to send a mail using PHP, but I am unsuccessful in it. Can you please see the code and highlight my mistakes. I host my website in ipage.com

The code is

```
<?php

$username = $_POST['userName'];
$useremail = $_POST['userEmail'];
$userphone = $_POST['userPhone'];
$usermsg = $_POST['userMsg'];

 $host = "smtp.ipage.com";
 $username = "prashanth@pe***ll.in";
 $password = "******";

if(_POST)
{
    $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
   array ('host' => $host,
     'auth' => true,
     'username' => $username,
     'password' => $password));

    $smtp->send("prashanth@petrawill.in",$usermsg,$useremail);
    header('location: contact.html');
}

else
{
    echo "This might be the worst piece of code that I have written";
}

?>
```

Comment: Without at least the code of Mail::send we can't help you.

Answer (score 1):

I assume Mail is initialized already. so

```
if (_POST)
```

should be

```
if ($_POST)
```

but I would rather see:

```
if (isset($_POST)) {
```

Comment: This is not her problem. PHP will automatically create the constant _PHP and fill it with "_PHP" which is true. So the code gets executed.

Comment: Actually that depends. Maybe he has a custom error handler in a framework he uses which dies on a E_NOTICE ?

Answer (score 0):

Type `_POST` will be `$_POST`, if you wanted to see its a `post` request use this

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
   $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
   array ('host' => $host,
     'auth' => true,
     'username' => $username,
     'password' => $password));

    $smtp->send("prashanth@petrawill.in",$usermsg,$useremail);
    header('location: contact.html');
}
```

If doesn't work post Mail class, please don't expose your actual credential to the world

Answer (score 0):

if u use isset in the condition then only the block will be excecuted

```
if($_POST)
{
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
array ('host' => $host,
 'auth' => true,
 'username' => $username,
 'password' => $password));

$smtp->send("prashanth@petrawill.in",$usermsg,$useremail);
header('location: contact.html');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I personally use [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) you can find the library on GitHub: https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer.

The code I use to do it is below:

```
<?php
require_once '../class.phpmailer.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true); //defaults to using php "mail()"; the true param means it will throw exceptions on errors, which we need to catch

try {
  $mail->AddReplyTo('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
  $mail->AddAddress('whoto@otherdomain.com', 'John Doe');
  $mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
  $mail->AddReplyTo('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
  $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer Test Subject via mail(), advanced';
  $mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!'; // optional - MsgHTML will create an alternate automatically
  $mail->MsgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'));
  $mail->AddAttachment('images/phpmailer.gif');      // attachment
  $mail->AddAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.gif'); // attachment
  $mail->Send();
  echo "Message Sent OK</p>\n";
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
  echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
}
?>
```

Comment: This is not an answer at all! If OP's asking to correct his/her code, proposing using _another_ solutions is **wrong**.

Comment: @trejder no it's not. If it helps the OP get to his end goal then it's a valid answer.

Comment: @Styphon As far as I know, Stack Overflow is a _developers Q&A_, where we are focused on _solving particular problem_, not on bringing any possible solution. If you give answer like that, you start an opinion-based discussion, not focused on key problem. If you ask me, how to fix a broken key on your keyboard and I answer you: get a touch device, they don't have problems with keyboards, you most likely be really pissed of with such answer, won't you? So, once again -- proposing completely different solution is wrong. I don't know, if this is written in FAQ or it just an unspoken rule here.